# Basis of null space of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a block matrix
$$
V=\begin{bmatrix} 0_{\hat{n}\times n} & I_{\hat{n}\times \hat{n}} & 0_{\hat{n}\times l} & 0_{\hat{n}\times q}\\ 
A_{p\times n} & 0_{p\times \hat{n}} & B_{p\times l} & 0_{p\times q}
\end{bmatrix},
$$ where $0$ and $I$ are zero and identity matrices respectively. Then $Ker(V)$ (basis of null space of $V$) is *shown* as
$$
ker(V)=\begin{bmatrix} V_1 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
V_3 & 0\\
0 & I_{q\times q}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $\begin{bmatrix} V_1 \\
V_3
\end{bmatrix}
$ is a basis matrix for $Ker([A\ B])$, and not explicitly writing all the matrix dimensions.

I am trying to figure out how $Ker(V)$ is obtained. My attempt is considering a vector $\tilde{V}=
\begin{bmatrix} v_n\\
v_{\hat{n}} \\
v_l\\
v_q 
\end{bmatrix},
$ of dimension $(n+\hat{n}+l+q)\times 1$ and then using the equality $V\tilde{V}=0$, which is not leading me to the given expression of $Ker(V)$. Kindly clarify my query.

Answer (score 1):

The way you do it is not wrong.
Continue the work you have done so far,
you can try considering for what $\tilde{V}$ satisfies $V\tilde{V}$,
then you should obtain the following equations:

1. $Av_n+Bv_l=0$
2. $Iv_{\hat{n}}=0$
3. $0v_q=0$

then you are not far away from the answer :)